# How can I mock a dummy token for login using Google OAuth in android?

Tags: android, ruby, oauth, server, google-signin

Since I'm not really into android development, is it possible to generate the token/code that will be generated for google oauth login without coding it in android?

If I understood it correctly, basically client / application will generate a `one-time-token`, pass it to the Server. Server will exchange it with more permanent token `(access token?)`, and using this `(access token?)`, server can then request the user's data to google.

but, is it possible to generate the `one-time-token` without coding it in android?